# CSS Grid without Media Queries?

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid, grid-layout

I have a simple grid, below, which works but I've been scratching my head on how to eliminate the media queries. Am I overthinking this, or is there a more efficient way to do this without media queries?

```
.wrap {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.wrap>div {
    padding: 1em;
    border: solid orange 1px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .wrap {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrap {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the media queries? As an academic project/thought exercise, or to meet a requirement? My personal preference would be to retain the media queries, and adjust the means by which I adjust the display; for example: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x2na7so0/), using CSS custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong or inefficient with using media queries with grid. You can avoid them in certain scenarios (eg. if you have a list of the uniform cards) if you wish, by using auto-placement. The code would look somehow like that:

```
.listing {
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
.listing .wide {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

This code comes from [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Realizing_common_layouts_using_CSS_Grid_Layout#A_product_listing_with_auto-placement) where you can learn more about this functionality and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Designating `dense` will make sure that all available placements are filled, so is there a difference between `auto-fill` and `auto-fit` in such a scenario?